Universal Derailleur Hangar (UDH) lack of thread prep
I'm building up a Trek Roscoe frameset.  As I began working with the thru axle--UDH hanger system in prep for installing the rear derailleur and the rest of the drivetrain, the instructions from SRAM and Trek Roscoe service manual really emphasizes no grease is to be used on the thread surfaces that engage to fix the hanger to the UDH compatible frame. They even invoke the "rider safety" warning, should grease be used here.

Below is a screen shot from the Roscoe service manual.  The overall UDH system can be seen including the hanger fixing bolt (the area that should not have grease and does not have any thread prep whatsoever), and the thru axle which ends up threading into internal threads of the hanger bolt. So, the UDH bolt has external threads that fix derailleur to frame and internal threads to accept and secure the thru axle (grease use is instructed for these particular threads.  I certainly would never put a ungreased thru axle in place).  Note the warning about greasing the hanger bolt threads. Why such emphasis about this?


What is the reasoning behind this emphasis? Why should there be no grease here?  Indeed, examining the male threads of the bolt, I find no evidence of even any thread prep of any kind.  I thought that strange that not even any dry loctite was used, since I presume the grease ban is perhaps related to the need for the rear derailleur to be positioned just so, thus making it so that the derailleur hanger must be held in its designed spot, positioned against the frame or a rotational stop tab on the frame.  Fixed in place. Is the thinking that grease on the threads would cause it to loosen?
But no thread prep whatsoever...

Can anyone shed any light on why one shouldn't grease these threads? If the prescribed torque is met, shouldn't the hanger be fixed in place regardless of grease or other prep?  What have we to fear here?

It's derailleur hanger, the part on which the derailleur hangs. Hangar is a building or structure designed to hold aircraft or spacecraft.

Can we really trust SRAM's view on thread prep after the shifter recall? (due to overapplication of Loctite). Grease threads with bolt torque check on regular service is best practice.

@g kertesz So even if I have Flight Deck compatible components, it's still just a hanger?  Point taken. Thanks.

I've noticed this too, but every SRAM mountain rd from recent years I can remember has the white pre-applied threadlocker. I don't know what their big fear is here but bare metal on metal is a hard no from me.

Greasing threads changes the pressure applied by the bolt for a given torque. I guess that SRAM was required to provide a maximum mechanical load exerted on the bike's frame by the UDH, and this value could be exceeded if grease was applied - so SRAM are safe in the case of cracked frames and injured riders.

@reciprocallettuce An M10 fastner has a typical recommended  torque of 23Nm for aluminium. I doubt most people apply more than 6Nm to the deralleur bolt. Grease or no grease on the threads doesn't take us near the higher number.

I was curious myself, so asked SRAM Rider Support.
This is what they say about this matter:

The key point is to avoid applying grease to the UDH bolt threads.
This is because the specified torque value for the UDH hanger’s bolt
is 25Nm, which is a 'dry torque.' Grease would reduce friction,
leading to over-tightening even at the correct torque setting, which
could damage the hanger threads or the hanger itself, creating a
safety concern.
Additionally, grease should not be applied where the
hanger interfaces with the frame's dropout. While this is less
critical, it can affect the function of the hanger. UDH hangers are
designed to rotate backward to absorb impacts, and greasing this
interface may cause the hanger to rotate out of position more easily
than intended.
For best results, it’s important to follow the
manual’s recommendations to ensure proper function and avoid any
safety issues.


Per my comment I see they have gone for top torque for the material. I don't see these being much fun to remove after some years of neglect, but we'll see, I suppose!

Thanks! @g.kertesz,  I emailed SRAM myself but have not heard back. Dry torque and prevent damage to frame at all costs. I don't see a backwards rotation being helpful on a bang hard enough to turn the hanger. Besides, my UDH sits in an incomplete cutout in the frame (a shaped recess, IOW) & would give a buffer of a whole millimeter if it rotated back. Anyway, I applaud a universal something on a modern bike!

I'm also disappointed to see this reasoning. Every one of these in the world being a dry aluminum-on-aluminum interface will lead to some rough moments with corrosion, especially because the nature of a replaceable hanger is sometimes they get replaced in the middle of a ride. It's true that doing it dry is one way of getting to a controlled amount of thread preload, but it's not the only way.

Taking into account @reciprocal lettuce comment "Greasing threads changes the pressure applied by the bolt for a given torque." and the fact that the hanger bolt also accepts the thru axel, thus hollow, and it also takes the torque forces of the thru axel and shares the forces of the rear wheel, I would think this comment rings true "so SRAM are safe in the case of cracked frames and injured riders", on other words SRAM are playing it very safe.
